# Fix node positions using klay layout in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

Is there a way to manually fix (x,y) position of the nodes using klay layout in cytoscript.js? Or would it be easier to use elkjs to do this?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Klay library does not have facilities to set restrictions on node positions.

There are two major classes of layouts:

(1) Force-directed (e.g. CoSE, Cola): You can just lock a node and its position is fixed in the physics simulation.

(2) Geometric (e.g. Klay, concentric): Either the algorithm supports restrictions on node position or it doesn't.  If there's no option explicitly available in the layout itself, then it's not possible.